# Jython: "no viable alternative at input" when i try to append to list of strings

Tags: java, python, jython

Attempting to re-write the `Minecraft Launcher` in `jython` as i have a rather basic knowledge of `java` but i believe im competent enough with `python` to undertake this task. I've been translating the decompiled classes as best as i can, but i'm encountering this **SyntaxError** whenever i try to append strings to my list **launchParameters**.

The reason why i'm puzzled as to why this is happening is because the first `.append()` worked for my list, but after that i get the mentioned **SyntaxError** thrown at me from the console.

```
@classmethod
def main(cls, paramArrayofString):
    maxHeap = 1024
    minHeap = 511
    runtimeMemory = float(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / maxHeap / maxHeap)

    if (runtimeMemory > minHeap):
        LauncherFrame.main(paramArrayofString)
    else:
        try:
            someString = CraftiLauncher.__class__.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().toURI().getPath()

            launchParameters = []

            if (Util.getPlatform() == "Windows"):
                launchParameters.append("javaw")
            else:
                launchParameters.append("java")

            launchParameters.append("-Xmx1024m") #This one appears to work
            launchParameters.append("-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true") #This is where i get my first error
            launchParameters.append("-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false")
            launchParameters.append("-Dsun.java2d.opengl=false")
            launchParameters.append("-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false")

            launchParameters.append("-classpath")
            launchParameters.append(someString)
            launchParameters.append("net.Crafti.LauncherFrame")

            localProcessBuilder = ProcessBuilder(launchParameters)
            localProcess = localProcessBuilder.start()

            if (localProcess == None):
                sys.exit()
```

if there's anything i need to elaborate on, please ask; if you think there's a page that might help me, feel free to link it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'm not entirely sure why i was getting the error, but it seems that just a simple fix of code indentation was the answer the whole time.

I didn't even change the indentation at all; i just simply dedented and indented everything again and now it works!